# Angular 2 - Images not showing on safari

Tags: angular, image, safari

My question is about image tag on safari browser.
I have code in angular 2 for displaying images on the page

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let i of incident.images" >
    <div class="image-tab">
        <img [src]="i && i.url != 'null' ? i.url : ''"  alt="img" >
    </div>
</div>
```

It works well with other browsers but not on Safari.
On Safari browser it just shows the string *img* which is alt attribute.

The point is that other images show up.

```
<label><img *ngIf="incident.status" [src]="'assets/img/status/' + incident.status + '.png'" alt="" style="height: 20px;">&ensp; {{incident.status || 'N/a'}} </label>
```

for example above code just works fine in the same file.

Right now I am think may be it's issue with  inside ***ngFor** but not sure.

Hope anyone can help me on this tricky thing!
Thank you.

Comment: null should not be single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try surrounding your statement in brackets `(i && i.url != 'null') ? i.url : ''` . Also depending on your value if null is not supposed to be hard coded string, leave out quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, Slobodan. 
After days of researching I found the issue. 
Actually it was not an issue on Angular but just https / http issue.
The image url saved on backend was http:// while the site was running on https://
It's strange that other browsers (google chrome and firefox) works fine with fetching http images from https but safari was strict.

Hope this would help you later!

Also those parentheses greatly helped me on other page. :)
Thank you again.